# How to mark question as answered when answer is in the comment

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I wonder how can someone mark question as answered if it gets answered through the comment?

Comment: There's no way. An answered question needs an answer, comments aren't answers.

Comment: ^ Ironically :-P ...

Comment: **Anybody** can post that answer.  The questioner is the most obvious candidate, SO is not a help desk.  When you commit to adding a Q+A for the world's benefit then you should be prepared to complete it.  If you are not committed then don't ask here.